# Parsing of multiple webpages using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to parse multiple web pages to extract specific text and images.  I have so far been able to parse one page, but I am looking for a way to run the script on all of the pages in the following link: [http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/search?cuisines[]=british](http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/search?cuisines%5b%5d=british) (there's 108 of them).

I basically need the images, along with the text next to them.

Comment: That's great. Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put *way* too much effort in this before i realised you just needed a for loop.

Here's an url to the same page, only this time with the page number as an argument:

```
http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/search?page=1&cuisines[0]=british&sortBy=lastModified
```

Change the page number, and you'll be able to get all 108 of them.

```
for i in range(1,109):
    url = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/search?page={pagenum}&cuisines[0]=british&sortBy=lastModified".format(pagenum = i)
    doYourThing(url)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ToonAlfrink - That was exactly what I needed!